# ExpressJS: JSDoc route with callbacks functions

Tags: node.js, express, jsdoc3

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Login
 * @function login
 * @param {function} noCacheRoute - Function for not cache
 * @param {function} isAuthenticated - Function for validate authenticate
 * @param {Object} req - Express request object
 * @param {Object} res - Express response object
 */
router.get('/login', noCacheRoute, isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('visitor/login');
});
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question:**

Exist some way of to document this cases of route with callbacks functions?

I looked the [jsdoc-route-plugin](https://github.com/bvanderlaan/jsdoc-route-plugin) module and this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215724/1116802) but not see that it adequate for the case.