# How to document useCallback with jsdoc?

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc, usecallback, react-usecallback

If I have my arrow function, wrapped in a React `useCallback`, how am I supposed to document it with JSDoc?

```js
const floopPig = useCallback((pigKey, floopCost) => {
  const pigAbility = pigs[pigKey];
  if (pigAbility.floopCost < magicPoints) {
    return pigAbility.activate()
  } else {
    throw new Error('Not enough magic points');
  }
}, [pigs, magicPoints])
```

I have been trying this in VSCode, but I haven't gotten anything to show up on hover over:

```js
/**
 * Floops a pig
 * @callback
 * @param {number} pigKey unique key for each pig
 * @param {number} floopCost how much the ability costs to activate
 */
```

I think I've followed the [documentation for `@callback`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback.html) correctly. But based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24215724/1075247) perhaps I'm using `@callback` for the wrong purpose?

How am I supposed to document this?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski that would make a good answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success documenting the callback function itself.

```js
const getNewToken = useCallback(
    /**
     * Requests a token, either by the normal flow or with a refresh token
     * @param {URLSearchParams} axiosBody The body of the axios request
     */
    async (axiosBody) => {
        //Function
    }, [myVar]);
```

Lower in the code, I can see intellisense working its magic when I call my function. I'm not 100% sure this is the best answer, but this is the best answer I've found
[image: Intellisense screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

A little simpler way I think is to just document the result callback, the internal passed callback will auto infer the types. Like

```
/**
 * @type {(param:string) => void}
 */
const callback = useCallback((param) => {
    param.trim(); // whatever
}, []);
```

[image]

Same result, but more concise.

Comment: does not work for me(