# Redundant JSDoc @return from an anonymous callback in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, jsdoc, jscs

I am using JSCS with Google preset style rules to check my code and I have a method in a DAO class defined like so:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new user into database.
 *
 * @param {User} user User to insert.
 * @return {User} Last inserted user.  // Redundant return statement
 * @throws Error if query fails.
 * @since 1.0
 */
add(user) {
  this.pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', user, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      conn.release();
      return this.getById(rows.insertId);
    });
  });
}
```

JSCS marks JSDoc `@return` tag as redundant because it can't find a return statement inside `add(user)` function scope, but it actually resides inside the anonymous callback `(err, rows) => { ... }`.

How can I correctly document that return statement? Is my approach wrong or bad in some way?

Comment: `add` indeed doesn't return anything. How does the `conn.query` method use the return value of its callback? In other words: why are you returning anything at all inside the `query` callback?

Comment: @apsillers The value returned from `add(user)` goes to server controller in order to manage authentication.

Comment: `add` does not return a value, and its return value cannot be based upon the result of an asynchronous operation like `query`. It is currently not possible to tell you how to correctly document your code, because your code doesn't work the way you intended. (Right now, the answer to your question is "You must remove the `@return` doc statement, because your function *does not return anything*.") See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/710446) for how to restructure your code to accept a callback instead of a returning a value.

Comment: @Emissary That resolves JSDoc warning but `conn.query(...)` (and so `this.pool.getConnection(...)`) do not return a `User`.

Comment: Yes, that has indeed been your problem all along -- neither `conn.query` nor `this.pool.getConnection` nor `add` ever returned a `User`, and they can't: `return`ing is a synchronous operation that must happen before any asynchronous operations resolve. See the link above.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks, checking that.

Comment: @apsillers Solved with promises and no return. JS asynchronous behavior is now a lot more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` does not return anything, so JSDoc is correct when it tells you that your `@return` tag is not appropriate. If you refactored your code so that `add` accepted a callback which is passed the result (as described in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/710446)), you would end up with

```
add(user, resultCallback) {
  this.pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', user, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      conn.release();
      resultCallback(this.getById(rows.insertId));
    });
  });
}
```

Call this with `add(user, result => { ... })` instead of `result = add(user)`.

How to document this? See [How to document callbacks using JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403887/how-to-document-callbacks-using-jsdoc) It would look like:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new user into database.
 *
 * @param {User} user User to insert.
 * @param {userResultCallback} resultCallback callback with last inserted user
 * @throws Error if query fails.
 * @since 1.0
*/
add(user, resultCallback) {
  //...
}

/**
 * Callback used to get a single User value.
 * @callback userResultCallback
 * @param {User} user Result of the callback
 */
```

The `@callback` at the bottom is stand-alone. It defines a type of callback function, which in this case is a callback that accepts a `User` as its only argument.